# Using Jquery - Find a particular class between two given classes and add content

Tags: jquery, search, filter

How can we find the existance of a particular class (say) class=sample, between two classes (say) class=start and insert some data into it.

In other words, I want to find the class="sample" between the starting and next class="start" and not the next to next class="start". Then, I would like to add some content into the found class="sample".

```
<div class="start">abc...</div> --->BETWEEN THIS CLASS
<div class="level" id="a1">def...</div>
<div class="sample">INSERT SOME DATA HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> AND THIS CLASS
<div class="sample">NO DATA SHOULD BE INSTERTED HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> NOT THIS CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` and  `hasClass` to find desire element and add whatever you want.

```js
$('.start').each(function(index, element) {
  var find = $(this).next('div').next('div');
  if (find.hasClass('sample')) {
    find.append('  added some data');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start">abc...</div> --->BETWEEN THIS CLASS
<div class="level" id="a1">def...</div>
<div class="sample">INSERT SOME DATA HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> AND THIS CLASS
<div class="sample">NO DATA SHOULD BE INSTERTED HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> NOT THIS CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
$('.start').siblings('.sample').first().append(' HELLO DATA HERE')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start">abc...</div> --->BETWEEN THIS CLASS
<div class="level" id="a1">def...</div>
<div class="sample">INSERT SOME DATA HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> AND THIS CLASS
<div class="sample">NO DATA SHOULD BE INSTERTED HERE</div>
<div class="level" id="a2">jkl...</div>
<div class="start">mno...</div> ---> NOT THIS CLASS
```